# MonoDevelop tries to sign assembly despite being configured to NOT sign assemblies

Tags: log4net, monodevelop, monomac, assembly-signing

I want to build log4net 1.2.11 (in MonoDevelop 3.0.5 on OS X 10.6.8).
I get this error:

> error CS1548: Error during assembly signing. The specified key file `......\log4net.snk' does not exist

... even though the project is configured to NOT sign assemblies:

[image]

How to make MonoDevelop understand that it should not worry about signing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line in log4net's `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile(@"..\..\..\log4net.snk")]
```

Removing this line solves the problem.